# Plot error bars (percentile)

Tags: matplotlib, percentile

I'm quite new to python and I need some help. I would like to plot errorbars equivalent to 1sigma standard deviations on my plot as the 16th and 84th percentile values of the distributions. I tried with (using matplotlib):

```
err=np.std(x)
```

but it just gives me the standard deviations. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want vertical error bars

```
 ax = plt.gca()
 ax.errorbar(x, y, yerr=np.vstack([error_low, error_high]))
 plt.draw()
```

where `error_low` and `error_high` are 1D sequences of the same length an `x` and `y`.  The error bars are drawn at `y[i] - error_low[i]` and `y[i] + error_high[i]`.

`matplotlib` just draws what you tell it to, it is your job to provide the semantics.

[`errorbar` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar)

Comment: You added on error bar of the value you specified, `matplotlib` only does the drawing, it does not do semantics (that is your job ;)).

Comment: give a look at [scoreatpercentile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.scoreatpercentile.html)

Comment: @tcaswell: what does the error "TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable" mean?

Comment: @ely you are trying to call a function with `f[a]` instead of `f(a)`.  If that does not make enough sense, open a new question