# How can i use standard deviation as my error bound in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to have error bounds in `Line2D` for a list which I plot using `plt.plot` but I can't find a way to show the error bars based on the standard deviation of that list.

Let's say `licorPhotometricSouthList` is a list filled with numbers and
`errorbar` is its standard deviation. How can I graph this?

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```py
errorbar=np.std(licorPhotometricSouthList)
plt.plot( signal.savgol_filter(licorPhotometricSouthList, 51, 3), label="Licor Photometric south")
```

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html something like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot error bars (percentile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071259/plot-error-bars-percentile)

Comment: Close but this method requires to input x and y. in this list i just have a buncha numbers without specific y

Comment: How do you imagine this numbers plotted? Most likely, you'll have two coordinates (one are you numbers -- presumably the y axis, and the other could be just `range(len(yourlist))`).

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry about this